# are op amps related to battery amper?

Tags: operational-amplifier, source

My question is simple. Can I use Lm324n while it has been directly connected to different types of batteries? For example series AA batteries Or Use 12V automobile car with 60 Ah.

Comment: Simultaneously?  No.  You shouldn't have multiple power sources connected to a single device like that.

Comment: Why not ?! If I make serries of batteries Or ... I have Almost same single bigger source. Isn,t This correct ?

Answer (score 2):

An LM324 op-amp requires a DC supply that can be as low as 3V or as high as 32 volts. The ampere hour rating of the battery is irrelevant.

[Here's](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm124-n.pdf) the data sheet that tells you all the specifications for the LM324.

Comment: My Answer was completely here. I wanted know "role" of current flow.

Comment: The current is about 1mA per op-amp or 4mA for the full package however, I think there may be a translation issue here so please let me know if this is not the answer.

Comment: Emmmm Let me know Can I look to op amps as a Voltage source ? By the other hand If I use a few AA batteries or A Automobile one Will op amps damage ?